# intermittent build problem in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, build

I have a large WPF solution running around for 2 years. Now we're running an automated build environment for that solution when the strangest thing happened.

In **50%** of our builds, I get this error:

> Exception:  Unable to cast object of
>   type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'
>   to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Border'. 
>   Error at object
>   'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'
>   in markup file ...

It seems simple enough. The problem is that my code behind is the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SiSM.Episode.Mishap.SpecializationList" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:Utils.Converters;assembly=Utils" ...>
    <Border x:Name="root"  BorderThickness="0.5">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelRoot" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                ...
            </StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer>
                ...
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The error is here because if I switch the stackpanel for a dockpanel the error message changed to a dockpanel.

My build environment is the following:

Copy the code to a build folder:

```
private void CopyCode(string sourceDir, string destinationDir) {
            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
                if (!dirPath.Contains(".svn") && !dirPath.Contains(@"\bin") && !dirPath.Contains(@"\obj")) {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourceDir, destinationDir));
                }
            }

            foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
                if (!newPath.Contains(".svn") && !newPath.Contains(@"\bin") && !newPath.Contains(@"\obj")) {
                    string dest = newPath.Replace(sourceDir, destinationDir);
                    File.Copy(newPath, dest);
                }
            }

            Worker.ReportProgress(5, "Copy done");
        }
```

And build the solution:

```
private void Compile(string buildConfiguration) {
            Engine engine = new Engine();

            FileLogger logger = new FileLogger { Parameters = @"logfile=C:\builds\build.log" };
            engine.RegisterLogger(logger);

            BuildPropertyGroup bpg = new BuildPropertyGroup();
            bpg.SetProperty("Configuration", buildConfiguration, true);
            engine.GlobalProperties = bpg;

            var project = new Project(engine);
            project.Load(ProjectFilePath);

            bool success = engine.BuildProject(project);

            engine.UnregisterAllLoggers();
}
```

Is anything wrong here or is there any known problem with WPF and Microsoft build engine?

**Edit 1**

I found when the error occurs. If I run the automated build app for the first time, it always succeeds, but if I run it a seconds time the above error occurs. So that's probably something I forgot to close that's creating the error.

I added a `engine.Shutdown();` at the end of the Compile method but it didn't fix the problem.

**Edit 2**

Thanks to @swiszcz suggestion, just found the weirdest thing. The file SpecializationList.g.cs (on obj folder) changes between the first and second build

First build

```
void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
switch (connectionId)
{
case 1:
this.stackPanelRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(target));
return;
case 2:

#line 63 "..\..\..\Mishap\SpecializationList.xaml"
((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(target)).Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.buttonShowGlobalView_Click);
...
```

Second Build

```
void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
switch (connectionId)
{
case 2:
this.stackPanelRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(target));
return;
case 3:
...
```

It increases 1 on the switch condition, and on the second build he's unable to convert a Button (case 2) to a StackPanel (case 1).

Comment: Is it possible you are running two builds at the same time? They would end up sharing a folder for code generation, which may result in that type of problem.

Comment: I use an app to build the solution and I only have 1 running. Plus the breakpoints on that app tell me only one build is running each time. Also I manually delete the code folder before each build (If I forget to do that the app will sends a warning and stops the building process).

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405681/xaml-parsing-exception) may be related.

Comment: It probably is, the stack trace is similar. Sadly it's still unawnsered

Comment: Are you using Clickonce deployment like in the other question?

Comment: The objective was to use clickonce at the end. But while trying to find reproduce the error, I was able to do it only by copying the code and run the build engine ( the 2 methods above ).

Comment: Insipred by @CodeNaked's suggestion: Does visual studio do parallel builds for C# as well? Could be part of the problem.

Comment: @jdv-Jan de Vaan, based on your comment I did a few more tests and did found something. The application always succeeds the first time I build it, but if I build it again without closing the builder app, it gives the above error. This happens with or without visual studio opened. I'll edit the question to give the new feedback

Comment: @Daniel - Did you try calling [UnloadAllProjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.unloadallprojects.aspx)?

Comment: @CodeNaked I think Engine.Shutdown() should do it, but I already tried both alternatives (Shutdown and UnloadAllProjects) but is still gives me the error.

Comment: @Daniel - Shutdown just calls UnregisterAllLoggers and does some "node shutdown", but doesn't explicitly unload the projects. When you reproducing the error, do you perform both CopyCode and Compile each time? Or just CopyCode once, then call Compile twice? Is CopyCode always to the same target folder?

Comment: @CodeNaked I also tried to skip CopyCode and delete the bin and obj folders of the crashing project by hand. If I didn't deleted it, since it's a build and it has no code changes, he just keep the dll's from the first build and everything works fine. If he builds the dll's for a second time, I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

My gues: when I had a very simlilar error, it was caused by erroreus .g.cs file generation. Look in your .g.cs file for casting stackPanelRoot to Border. 
A walkaround in xaml: change x:Name="stackPanelRoot" to Name="stackPanelRoot", or remove x:Name, if possible.

Comment: I change the x:Name to Name. It's not possible to remove it because I'm using it on code behind. As for the .g.cs file, it seems ok. The only two references there to stackPanelRoot are internal System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel stackPanelRoot; and this.stackPanelRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(target));

Comment: Wait... I was wrong... if it's: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Border'" then you may have your StackPanel being assigned to border 'root'.
 
In a bug we had it was possible to remove the control's name, and that solved the issue.

Comment: I'm confuse. To remove the Border name or the StackPanel name?

Comment: So check this.root in your g.cs. Or try removing the border's 'root' name.

Comment: on g.cs I have two references to the root element: internal System.Windows.Controls.Border root; and this.root = ((System.Windows.Controls.Border)(target));

Comment: Then the exception may occure on: this.root = ((System.Windows.Controls.Border)(target)).
Try removing temporarly the name for border.

Comment: If I take the name of the border, it gives me another error:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'. On my .g.cs file i got the line this.stackPanelRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(target)); on System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect() method. that's probably where's the error but it creeps me out that he's corruption obj files.